# appcelerator broadcast live video to server

Tags: video, appcelerator, live, appcelerator-titanium

I'm thinking of developing an app that broadcast video to a web and other users can watch the live videos on the web and the app.

i want method or module to broadcast video from camera to server directly as it recording in Appcelerator titanium , and how implement it in my app
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't anything that is available in the core API and something very specific for a module. So you either have to develop your own module or get somebody to create one for you (have a look at the job section in the Ti-Slack at http://tislack.org/). But you would need to provide more information like: are you using an existing provider to stream to, which mobile platform are you aiming at,...

Otherwise your question is very broad and when this is already the point where you are stuck you need to do more research to create this kind of app.